# ol.proj.transform Zoomify to EPSG:4326

Tags: openlayers-3

Is there any way to transform from Zoomify (with a specific width and height) to [long, lat] coordinates ? 
I saw the documentation (for 3.6) and it seems that ol.proj.transform method does not accept ZOOMIFY as ol.proj.ProjectionLike parameter.

Currently, I have some marker coordinates saved by LeafletJS library into database and I need to project them into [long, lat] coordinates to display them with a OpenLayer 3.6 map. The tiles for the map are the same as it was for Leaflet library.
If needed, here is the code for initiating the ol3 map:

```
var proj = new ol.proj.Projection({
        code: 'ZOOMIFY',
        units: 'pixels',
        extent: [0, 0, width, height]
    }),
    map = new ol.Map({
        target: this.get('view').$().attr('id'),
        view: new ol.View({
            projection: proj,
            center: [width/2, - height/2],
            zoom: 1,
            extent: [0, -height, width, 0]
        }),
        controls: []
    });
    ......
    var layer = new ol.source.Zoomify({
        url: url,
        size: [width, height],
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
    });
    map.addLayer(layer);
```

Also, the code that I'm using to add the markers is:

```
pos = ol.proj.transform([posX, posY], 'ZOOMIFY', 'EPSG:4326'),
marker = new ol.Overlay({
    position: pos,
    positioning: 'center-center',
    element: domElement,
    stopEvent: false
});
map.addOverlay(marker);
```

I need to mention that I am really new with this framework, so any hint can be helpful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you did not need to transform the coordinates since the frameworks know that the coordinates are in the ZOOMIFY format (from the map creation, see above lines).

I solved the problem with the following code:

```
pos = [posX, posY],
marker = new ol.Overlay({
    position: pos,
    positioning: 'center-center',
    element: domElement,
    stopEvent: false
});
map.addOverlay(marker);
```